# Webmail or PHP mail function both not sending email

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, email, webmail

I tried to send mail from my Web Application with my email function. Result shows success but no email was in inbox/spam in receiver's email account. I tried different approaches like smpt, simple mail() but no success. [I used WordPress and Codeigniter for my applications/sites.]

So, i tried to send mail from Webmail (using roundcube) like-wise shows success and is found in send list but no email received in receiver's inbox/spam.

I don't know what is causing this. Is there error in my Mailing code OR in my Hosting mail settings.
Please help me.

Comment: It's probably the receiving end rejecting the message. Try to send it to another mail box, or still better, make sure you have things like SPF, DKIM, and the like, set up properly.

Comment: _Not enough information for anything other than a guess_ But lots of hosts insist that mail must be sent **from** an address that really exists on the associated mail system for your hosting package i.e. must be sent **from** `a.real.address@yourdomain.tld`